# Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I'm upgrading from Angular 8.2 to 9.1 and I'm trying to change private fields to be `#fieldName: any` as allowed by [TS 3.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) instead of `private fieldName: any`. And I get the compiler error saying

> Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "esnext"
        "target": "es2015",
    }
}
```

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "typescript": "3.8.3"
}
```

Comment: Uh, the error message is wrong, since ES2015 does *not* have private identifiers. EDIT: also apparently I can't read, as it's the TS compiler...

Comment: @VLAZ is there a source that identifies the fact that ES2015 doesn't have private identifiers? 

Comment: @duhaime [private fields are a Stage 4 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/HEAD/finished-proposals.md) (check under "Class Fields" in the table) thus cannot be in the spec. Speaking of [the 2015 spec does not contain them](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/), nor does [the released spec - ES2021/ES12](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/). Private fields are included in [the latest draft](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-PrivateIdentifier), therefore it's expected they'd be in the upcoming ES2022/ES13 spec.

Answer (score 8):

in the `tsconfig.json` you must replace the es2015 for the mostly recent version to suport this. Try replace the `es2015` per `es2017`, I use es2017 is the best verion for this in my opinion

Comment: This does not solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have "type":"module" in your package.json, always add "module":"commonJS" in your tsconfig when using the latest target or beyond ES2015

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "strict": true,
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```