# Firebase Cloud Functions Error: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher

Tags: typescript, firebase

When I transpile my index.ts file to index.js like:

```
tsc index.ts
```

I get the following errors:
../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/crc32c.d.ts:68:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

68     #private;
~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.d.ts:253:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

253     #private;
~~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/hash-stream-validator.d.ts:11:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

11     #private;

As per this post: [Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher (Angular 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67019328/private-identifiers-are-only-available-when-targeting-ecmascript-2015-and-higher)

All I should need to do is target es2017 in my tsconfig.json file. However, I already do this and still get the errors.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I have tried many different versions of the above with no luck. This problem first appeared when updating to firebase-admin ^11.3.0, and I am now wondering if perhaps I need to update another package for this to work.

For your reference, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec --timeout 10000",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.2.0",
    "@firebase/app-compat": "^0.1.28",
    "@types/rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "csv-parse": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.1.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "puppeteer": "^10.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "typesense": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.33.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: It seems that the thing I was doing wrong was:
tsc index.ts

I needed to run the the tsc command by itself in the functions directory. Doing so made tsc command use the tsconfig.json file.. before it was not doing so.